# Two primary keys class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I started doing a new project and im trying to adapt my database that i created before to the database on Entity Framework, i have 2 tables: Challenge and Coment and what i want to do is associate a coment to a challenge.
What i did before using Entity Framework:

```
 public class Challenge
{
    public int ChallengeId { get; set; } // id associado ao desafio
    public string TypeWork { get; set; } // tipo de trabalho que o cliente pretende que seja feito
    public string Description { get; set; } // Descricao detalhada do desafio
    public decimal Value { get; set; } // Valor em pontos ou em dinheiro pago ao vencedor do desafio
    public DateTime DateCriation { get; set; } // data da criação do anuncio
    public DateTime DataEnd { get; set; } // data em que expira o desafio
    public int? WinnerSolution { get; set; } // id da solucao vencedora
    public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; } // chave estrangeira para tipo de pagamento
    public int ComentChallengeId { get; set; } // chave estrangeira para Comentario do desafio
    public virtual ICollection<TypePayment> TypePayment { get; set; } // coleccao de tipos de pagamento 

    public virtual ICollection<ComentChallenge> ComentChallenge { get; set; } // lista de comentarios associados ao desafio

}
```

**ComentChallenge class**

```
namespace CrowdTouring.Models
{
    public class ComentChallenge
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int ComentChallengeId { get; set; } // id do comentario do desafio
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int ChallengeId { get; set; } // id do desafio
        public string Title { get; set; } // titulo do comentario
        public string Description { get; set; } // Descricao do comentario
        public DateTime date { get; set; } // data do comentario

    }
}
```

In the comentChallenge class i created 2 primary keys 1 to associate to the challenge and the other to associate to the coments about the challenge am i using the right approach how can i do that this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using the MobelBuilder in the DbContext to take care of it. Let it know that the two are related. I modified your code below and added an example of a context.

By using the conventions the foreignkey id's will automaticly be generated for you in the database and you can use the navigation properties in code to access the relations.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            builder.Entity<Challenge>().HasMany(x => x.CommentChallenges).WithOne(y => y.Challenge);
        }
    }

public class Challenge
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // id associado ao desafio
    public string TypeWork { get; set; } // tipo de trabalho que o cliente pretende que seja feito
    public string Description { get; set; } // Descricao detalhada do desafio
    public decimal Value { get; set; } // Valor em pontos ou em dinheiro pago ao vencedor do desafio
    public DateTime DateCriation { get; set; } // data da criação do anuncio
    public DateTime DataEnd { get; set; } // data em que expira o desafio
    public int? WinnerSolution { get; set; } // id da solucao vencedora
    public int PaymentTypeId { get; set; } // chave estrangeira para tipo de pagamento
    public virtual ICollection<TypePayment> TypePayment { get; set; } // coleccao de tipos de pagamento 

    public virtual ICollection<ComentChallenge> CommentChallenges { get; set; } // lista de comentarios associados ao desafio

}

namespace CrowdTouring.Models
{
    public class ComentChallenge
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } // id do comentario do desafio
        public string Title { get; set; } // titulo do comentario
        public string Description { get; set; } // Descricao do comentario
        public DateTime date { get; set; } // data do comentario
        public virtual Challenge Challenge { get; set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: 2 questions: where you put that modelBuilder? and how it works in terms of database ?

Comment: It's in the application DB context. Maybe this link will help you https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application. In terms of the database it will create a column for you for the foreign key and it will, in case of a many to many relation, generate an extra table to handle the matching. This column will be invisible for you in code since it's managed by EF

Comment: hmmm i kinda now that concepts but in this case i have a 1 to many relationship, i just need that my class ComentChallenge associate many coments to 1 challenge

Comment: If you specify this with the modelBuilder, like in my example, there will be a 1 to many relationship. You can just add it by using Challenge.CommentChallenges.Add(<comment obj>).

When trying to acces it use: Challenge.CommentChallenges or if you want to view the challenge from the comment side CommentChallenge.Challenge

Comment: thanks, and the composite primary keys should i maintain?

Comment: I would just use the convention of EF. So just the Id and nothing more ;)

Comment: i used the ER diagram to model the schema, and now i must change the approach cause of EF right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110258/discussion-between-tom-droste-and-filipe-costa).